# How can I compute ratios of large factorials without unnecessary overflows?

Tags: r, overflow, factorial

I'm writing a program (in R, in case that matters) in which I need to compute the number of unique permutations of a vector of elements, which can contain repeated values. The [mathematical formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203251/how-many-different-permutations-are-there-of-the-sequence-of-letters-in-mississ) for this is straightforward: the factorial of the total number of elements divided by the product of the factorials of the counts of each unique element. However, calculating the result naively is very likely to lead to overflows even when the actual answer is not very large. For example:

```
# x has 200 elements, but 199 of them are identical
x <- c(rep(1, 199), 2)
num_unique_permutations <- factorial(length(x)) / prod(factorial(table(x)))
```

If this didn't overflow, then `num_unique_permutations` would be 200!/(199!*1!) = 200. However, both 200! and 199! overflow the max value of a double, so the actual result is NaN. Is there a good way to do this calculation that will always avoid overflows (or underflows) as long as the answer itself doesn't overflow? (Or perhaps, as long as it doesn't come within a factor of `length(x)` of overflowing?)

---

(Note that R uses doubles for most numerical calculations, but the problem is not specific to doubles. Any numeric type with a range has the same problem. Also, I don't care about losing a bit of precision to floating point math, since I'm just using this to get a rough upper bound on something.)

Comment: A common practice is to use log in order to avoid overflows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R use `lfactorial`, to compute the logarithms of the numerator and of the denominator. Then exponentiate the appropriate difference.

```
numer <- lfactorial(length(x))
denom <- sum(lfactorial(table(x)))
exp(numer - denom)
#[1] 200
```

This can be easily written as a function.

```
num_unique_permutations <- function(x){
  numer <- lfactorial(length(x))
  denom <- sum(lfactorial(table(x)))
  exp(numer - denom)
}

num_unique_permutations(x)
#[1] 200
```

Comment: This is a simple and straightforward solution, and R even has a built-in function to facilitate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `gmp` library.

```
library(gmp)
factorial(as.bigz(length(x))) / prod(factorial(as.bigz(table(x))))
#[1] 200
```

Comment: Is this just using a numeric type that doesn't overflow?

Comment: Yes, as long at you have enough memory.